# People search working in sharepoint standard edition using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-2010

According to my question it is possible to do people search in sharepoint 2010 standard edition.

I have sharepoint 2010 enterprise edition and it's works fine for me.
I use jquery for people search.

So is it possible for sharepoint 2010 standard edition?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use 'Similar Results' this is suported only in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition.

More details: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx?Capability=Search